# How to do this edit in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Below is the example field:

```
Red Car TYDJJIJIDIJIJDIJDIJDJI  YEUE"
Green Car JHJDHUYUIHUJHJDHKJHKDHU  JKDO"
```

I would like a command which made the first two words jump into the space gap, so they became:

```
TYDJJIJIDIJIJDIJDIJDJI Red Car YEUE"
JHJDHUYUIHUJHJDHKJHKDHU Green Car JKDO"
```

Is there a command to do this as I have quite a lot to edit...

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression search-and-replace (Ctrl-H, check "regular expression"):

Search: (\S+ )(\S+ )(\S+ )(\S+)

Replace: $3$1$2$4

`(\S+ )` will match one or more non-space characters followed by a space, and will capture it into a group, which you then reference in the replace expression with the $X syntax. The fourth group is slightly different as it doesn't need to capture a trailing space.